# Is there a Java built-in construct like vb.net's Do Until Loop?

Tags: java

I am trying to make my code more readable and so it would be useful to use the following (or equivalent)

```
do
{
    ...
}
until(Display.isCloseRequested())
```

rather than

```
do
{
    ...
}
while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
```

but I can't seem to find something like this.

Yes, I don't like the 'java convention' of having the opening brace on the same line as the statement and the final statement on the same line as the closing brace. I prefer that code style.

Comment: Why is the first more readable than the second? Because the secobd has a single exclamation mark?

Comment: Also, if you start your project in 2016, theb use LWJGL 3 instead of 2

Comment: @Bálint I personally find the first more readable, so yes, I can understand why the asked the question. An exclamation mark can easily be overlooked, causing the reader to have to look over the code multiple times.

Comment: As you can see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html ... no there is no such thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Java doesn't have a `do-until` loop construct or similar. Just `do-while` with the opposite test as you indicated in the question, `for`, and `while`. All use "positive" tests (loop continues while test is true).

More in the JLS:

- [Control flow statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)
- [`for`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)
- [`while` and `do-while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Not the result I was hoping for but at least now I have another thing to add to the list of downfalls of Java! Thank you anyways

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want the `until` syntax, you can cheat a little and create an `until()` method that negates a boolean expression.

#### For example...

```
do {
    // something
} while (
    until(Display.isCloseRequested())
);

...

public static boolean until(boolean condition) {
    return !condition;
}
```

You can statically import the `until` method whenever you want to use it.

#### Although this introduces some issues:

- It **doesn't look very pretty**.
- It is unconventional and can cause confusion.